# .g.i.cs missing using statement for Telerik controls

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I've inherited a Silverlight application that is using Telerik controls. I'm pretty new to Silverlight, so a noob question follows. When trying to build the solution, I'm getting name could not be found errors for the Telerik controls. When I look at the *.g.i.cs files, the "using Telerik.Windows.Controls" is missing from the auto-generated files. Of course if I make the change directly, it gets over written when I do the build. How do I tell Silverlight to include the Telerik using statement when generating the .g.i.cs files?

Answer (score 1):

The fix is to include this in your control:

xmlns:input="clr-namespace ystem.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data.Input"